# How to disable deployment from particular account in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Here is my configuration for allowing certain account ID for deployment.

```
provider "aws" {
  #shared_credentials_file = "$HOME/.aws/credentials"
  region                  = "${var.region}"
  #profile = "customprofile"
  allowed_account_ids=["164*******65"] 
}
```

This is working fine, but I have configured multiple accounts, and I want to disallow some account IDs instead updating each time `allowed_acccount_ids` fields.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`forbidden_account_ids`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/index.html#forbidden_account_ids) as a blacklist instead of whitelisting accounts via `allowed_account_ids`.

Comment: To satisfy my curiosity, and maybe this is a dumb question, why are those parameters mutually exclusive? I assume this is some limitation in AWS.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I was also curious about the way and behind the scene mechanism of terraform, but your provided link answer me both.https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/index.html#getting-the-account-id

Comment: @MattSchuchard no reason that I know of. It's implemented directly in the provider config so nothing to do with AWS. I personally prefer whitelisting a single account and then symlinking that provider config in the relevant directories that need that AWS account.